# How To Generate A Token For Delegated Permissions (Microsoft Graph)

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, access-token, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I want to send messages to a team's channel.
So far, I've been able to create teams, create users among various other operations successfully, the token I generated works just fine. Sending messages to a channel however only works with delegated permissions and the request to send a message fails with error code 401.

*login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id/oauth2/v2.0/token* is the end point I'm using the default scope i.e. *graph.microsoft.com/.default* which informs the Microsoft Identity platform of Application Permissions of the App only, how do I modify the POST request to generate a token to honor delegated permissions for the App and send messages to the channel ?

In other words, I would like to know how to generate a token when making use of a Graph API that only supports delegated permissions ?

Comment: Please check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post-message?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http). At this point, you can send messages to a team channel using Delegated permissions only. So you need to make sure your AAD is designed in a way which supports it. Application permission won't work as its not supported, check the above documentation.

Comment: does it helped?

Comment: @Dhiwakar : carl and dev have given accurate answers to this question. Please let us know if you still face issues.

Comment: @Manish-MSFT, thank you so much for the assistance. I got it to work after taking a close look at the auth code flow and implementing it correctly, it's working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @Dev said in the comments is correct, you can [send messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post-message?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) to a team channel using **delegated permissions** only. So, you must grant delegated permissions to the application, and then grant **admin consent** for that permission.

As for the 401 error you received, I think you may have used the wrong authentication flow. When you use delegated permissions to obtain a token, you should use the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow), which requires you to log in to the user to obtain the authorization code, and then use the authorization code is redeemed for the access token.

Comment: How to get a delegated token without using the login form. In my case I need to save files to one drive account I have created for my application. So users don't have to log in. the app itself logins and upload files to OneDrive. My application a SPA (Angular)

Comment: @JeffinJ  Hello, I cannot answer your question in the comments because of the word limit. Can you post a question and link me to your question?

Comment: This is the link to my post. It has an active bounty on it that expires today. [How to get the Access Token for OneDrive API from Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66954353/11152084)

Comment: @JeffinJ  Okay, we will communicate in your post.